# Why does the NSDecimalNumber 10^-65 squared result in 10^126 instead of resulting in an Underflow Exception?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, floating-point, nsdecimalnumber, underflow

So here's the code:

```
NSDecimalNumber *test=[[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithInt:65];
number3=[[NSDecimalNumber one] decimalNumberByDividingBy:[[[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithInt:10] decimalNumberByRaisingToPower:test.integerValue]];
number3=[number3 decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:number3];
```

I expected the program to terminate with an underflow exception, but it didn't.  Moreover, taking an NSLog gives number3 as some huge number.  If I change "test" to anything below 64, it gives the correct output (that is, 10^(-2*test)).  Does anyone know what's going on here?  I mean, it's pretty easy to work around, but unless I'm missing something (which is quite possible), it seems like an error in the NSDecimalNumber class.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug.

`NSDecimalNumber` is [documented to support exponents from -128 to +127](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSDecimalNumber).  Clearly, (10<sup>-65</sup>)<sup>2</sup> has an exponent of -130, which is out of range.  However, instead of raising an exception, it's wrapping -130 to +126.

The [documented default behavior](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000179-defaultBehavior) of `NSDecimalNumber` is that “The methods assume your need for precision does not exceed 38 significant digits and raise exceptions when they try to divide by 0 or produce a number too big or too small to be represented.”

Since it's not raising an exception, I'd say you found a bug.  You can report it at http://bugreport.apple.com/.